# Get ON DELETE ON UPDATE actions in foreign keys constraints

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get actions in foreign keys changes (on delete/update).

I tried to check it looking in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`key_column_usage` 
WHERE `referenced_table_schema` = '{$this->dbName}'
AND `referenced_table_name` IS NOT NULL
AND `table_name` = '{$this->tableName}'
```

It shows something like this :

```
0 => 
array (size=12)
  'CONSTRAINT_CATALOG' => string 'def' (length=3)
  'CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'CONSTRAINT_NAME' => string 'profiles_ibfk_1' (length=15)
  'TABLE_CATALOG' => string 'def' (length=3)
  'TABLE_SCHEMA' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'TABLE_NAME' => string 'profiles' (length=8)
  'COLUMN_NAME' => string 'id' (length=2)
  'ORDINAL_POSITION' => string '1' (length=1)
  'POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT' => string '1' (length=1)
  'REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME' => string 'users' (length=5)
  'REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME' => string 'id' (length=2)

....
```

I tryed with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAITS too and i got:

```
0 => 
array (size=6)
  'CONSTRAINT_CATALOG' => string 'def' (length=3)
  'CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'CONSTRAINT_NAME' => string 'PRIMARY' (length=7)
  'TABLE_SCHEMA' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'TABLE_NAME' => string 'profiles' (length=8)
  'CONSTRAINT_TYPE' => string 'PRIMARY KEY' (length=11)

....
```

Nothing about actions on delete/update in 2 cases.

I can get it? How? if i can of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `UPDATE_RULE` and `DELETE_RULE` from the [`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/referential-constraints-table.html) information schema:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, UPDATE_RULE, DELETE_RULE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = '{$this->dbName}'
   AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
   AND TABLE_NAME = '{$this->tableName}'
```

As documented:

> The possible values for `UPDATE_RULE` or `DELETE_RULE` are `CASCADE`, `SET NULL`, `SET DEFAULT`, `RESTRICT`, `NO ACTION`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. If you just want the foreign keys updated on related records, then you are looking for foreign key constraints with the `CASCADE` option.  See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and read through the section on cascades.  If you want more complex actions on UPDATE/DELETE of a record, you will need triggers.  See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) for the syntax to create a trigger.